# Display NSManagedObject field in SwiftUI form

Tags: swiftui, nsmanagedobject

I want to display a form using the data from an NSManagedObject.

Here is my form:

```
struct RecordForm: View
{
    @State var record: Record // NSManagedObject

    var body: some View
    {
        Form
        {
            TextField("name", text: $record.recordName) // Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument type '_?'
        }
    }
}
```

So it's obviously not liking the optional value, but I cannot find the syntax to address this. Adding an exclamation mark doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Binding` has explicit constructor for optionals. Try the following

```
Form
{
    TextField("name", text: Binding<String>($record.recordName))
}
```

Comment: That solution does not work for me.